# How to use RouterFunction of Spring 5 in web project?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux

**Issue:**
On **Submit** button i call **`/hello`** but it gives me **HTTP Status 404**

I'm new on Spring 5 so help me, How can i forward **`/hello`** request. I want to implement important Spring 5 features : 
(1) Reactive programming support
(2) Functional web framework

[image]

[image]

**HelloHandler.java**

```
package com.demo;

import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.server.ServerRequest;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.server.ServerResponse;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

public class HelloHandler {
    public  Mono<ServerResponse> handleRequest(ServerRequest serverRequest) {
        return ServerResponse.ok().body(Mono.just("Hello World!"), String.class);
    }
}
```

**SpringAction.java**

```
package com.demo;

import static org.springframework.web.reactive.function.server.RequestPredicates.GET;
import static org.springframework.web.reactive.function.server.RequestPredicates.POST;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.server.RouterFunction;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.server.RouterFunctions;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.server.ServerResponse;

@Configuration
public class SpringAction {

    @Bean
    HelloHandler helloHandler() {
        System.out.println("SpringAction.helloHandler()");
        return new HelloHandler();
    }

    @Bean
    public RouterFunction<ServerResponse> helloRouterFunction(HelloHandler helloHandler) {
        return RouterFunctions.route(GET("/hello"), helloHandler::handleRequest)
                .andRoute(GET("/SpringFunctionalWebFramework/hello"), helloHandler::handleRequest);
    }     
}
```

**SpringFunctionalWebFramework-servlet.xml**

```
<beans xmlns = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:context = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

   <context:component-scan base-package = "com.demo" />

   <bean class = "org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
      <property name = "prefix" value = "/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
      <property name = "suffix" value = ".jsp" />
   </bean>

</beans>
```

**index.jsp**

```
<body>
    <h1>Hello World.</h1>
    <form action="hello" method="GET">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</body>
```

I also want to know that is it possible to use **RouterFunction** facility without Spring-boot or not?

Answer (score 0):

Your application depends on `spring-webmvc`, [as described in the Spring Boot reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-webflux), this will make your application a Spring MVC app. So you should first figure out what's bringing that dependency and remove it from your build.

Next, it seems your app doesn't have a `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class; if you want a good starting point, you should create your app using start.spring.io and select the webflux starter.

Next, Spring Boot doesn't need nor support `-servlet.xml` files. You should read up about Spring Boot in its reference documentation or take a look at [the Spring guides](https://spring.io/guides).

Spring WebFlux doesn't support JSPs, so there's no need to configure an internalviewresolver nor add JSP files in your app. You should instead look for a modern view technology like mustache, thymeleaf, etc (all listed on start.spring.io).

You can of course use Spring WebFlux without Spring Boot, [but it requires manual setup and deployment](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html#webflux-httphandler) (in an embedded or external container). I'd argue that Spring Boot is by far the easiest way.

Comment: thank you. 
But i want to implement Spring 5 **Reactive programming support**, **Functional web framework** in my web project.
so please suggest me the way how i can.

Comment: Already did. Creating a project from start.spring.io will fix most of your issues.

Comment: My requirement is i want to implement Spring 5 features in Spring web project. In the question you see that i share screenshots of my web project. It run perfectly but when i call `localhost:8080/SpringFunctionalWebFramework/hello` it give me 404 error